# displaying Wiki mobile page in UIWebView within UIPopoverController

Tags: uiwebview

I try to open wiki mobile version webpage by a UIWebView within a UIPopoverController. the problem is, not matter how I set my contentSizeForViewInPopover, or just UIWebView frame, or simply set UIWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES. the Wiki mobile version page content size seem to larger than my UIWebView. But if I use it on iPhone, there's no such problem. here's my code for popover controller:

```
//create a UIWebView UIViewController first
WikiViewController *addView = [[WikiViewController alloc] init];
addView.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0f);

//then create my UIPopoverController
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:addView];
popover.delegate = self;
[addView release];

//then get the popover rect
CGPoint pointforPop = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:selectAnnotationCord 
                                        toPointToView:self.mapView];
CGRect askRect = CGRectMake((int)pointforPop.x, (int)pointforPop.y+10, 1.0, 1.0);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:askRect 
                         inView:self.mapView 
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
[self.mapView deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
```

and this is my code on creating UIWebView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 wikiWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
 wikiWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
 //or No, doesn't matter, it all get larger than this
 wikiWebView.delegate = self;
 self.view = wikiWebView;
}
```

all code seem to be typical...
I wonder if anyone can shed me some light, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This is an enhanced version of auco answer, where if the viewport meta tag is not present it will be added:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    int webviewWidth = (NSUInteger)webView.frame.size.width;

    if (!webView.loading) {

        NSString *jsCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"try {var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');if (viewport != null) {viewport.setAttribute('content','width=%ipx, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1');} else {var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');viewPortTag.id='viewport';viewPortTag.name = 'viewport';viewPortTag.content = 'width=%ipx, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);}} catch (e) {/*alert(e);*/}", webviewWidth, webviewWidth];

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCmd];
    }
}
```

Here is the Javascript pretty formatted code we are injecting in the WebView with a width of 320px

```
try {
    var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
    if (viewport != null) {
        viewport.setAttribute('content',
                'width=320px, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1');
    } else {
        var viewPortTag = document.createElement('meta');
        viewPortTag.id = 'viewport';
        viewPortTag.name = 'viewport';
        viewPortTag.content = 'width=320px,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
    }
} catch (e) {
    /*alert(e);*/
}
```

you can remove the try/catch if you want.

Answer (score 2):

oh, i found in another QA that sometimes if html got a line "width=device-width", and you load a webview from popover controller, this popover controller will automatically send out device-width, not the view width you specified, and make your view ugly and funky. in that post it is a jQuery issue, and it solved with a jQuery way. In my problem, it is just a html issue in wiki mobile version. so I try another way, but similar.

I simple add a code in webViewdidload delegate method, first get URL html into a NSString, then use NSString instance method to search for "device-width" in loaded html, and replace it with my view width to make it a new NSString, then load this page with this new NSString. that's it.

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
if (!alreadyReload) 
{
    NSString *webHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:webView.request.URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSRange range = [webHTML rangeOfString:@"device-width"];
    if ((range.location!=NSNotFound)&&(range.length != 0)) 
    {
        webHTML = [webHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"device-width" withString:@"whatever width you need" options:0 range:range];
        [webView loadHTMLString:webHTML baseURL:wikiWebView.request.URL];
        alreadyReload = YES;
    }
}
}
```

something like this.

by the way, since I only use this on wiki mobile version, the html is simple and this kind of compare and replace is pretty easy. if you wanna use it in a more general case, you might use other way.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much more efficient to manipulate the device-width **via JavaScript** rather than altering the html *after* it has fully loaded and then reloading the full page with modified html again.

This should work (and also consider if it's even necessary to change the viewport width):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    if(aWebView.frame.size.width < aWebView.window.frame.size.width) {
        // width=device-width results in a wrong viewport dimension for webpages displayed in a popover
        NSString *jsCmd = @"var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');";
        jsCmd = [jsCmd stringByAppendingFormat:@"viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=%i, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1');", (NSUInteger)aWebView.frame.size.width];
        [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCmd];
    }
    // stop network indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```