# objective c: fit twitter page width in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, width, sizetofit

I have a UIWebview in which a twitter page loads. Because twitter is being opened from a mobile device it opens the mobile twitter which has a specific width depending on device, and device orientation. Now my query: my UIWebview's width is shorter than mobile twitters width so the user has to scroll sideways to read content. I do not want that and want to change the zoom or preferably the width of the twitter page so it can fit in my uiwebview.The height is fine, scrolling up or down is normal. I have tried using "setScalesPageTofit" in my "webViewDidFinishLoad" and that displays the whole twitter page going out of the webview bounds. I have also tried using "sizeTofit" but no success. If any more details required please left me know
Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this SO Post: [Getting iPhone's mobile twitter webapp inside UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639275/getting-iphones-mobile-twitter-webapp-inside-uiwebview).  The person who posted the question answered his own question.

The trick seems to be setting the correct "device-width".

Comment: okay I added some of the code from the link you provided (thanks for that by the way) but that created another issue- the content of the web view cannot be resized after running the code the first time. If I set the width 320 initially and then changed t0 400 for example, it remains 320. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @pnizzle: Is your question how to dynamically resize a UIWebView (e.g. when the orientation changes)?

Comment: No, that is not my question. Twitter page width is longer than the width of my uiwebview. I used the code from the link you provided, ran it with a width  of 320 and it Did resize the twitter page. After that I changed the width to the same width as my uiwebview which is 400px and it does not want to change from 320px anymore. Really weird. Changed first time but not anymore after that