# UIWebView not loading responsive web page correctly

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview

I am trying to load a responsive web page into a UIWebview, using the following code in my UIViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.webViewURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Rather than loading the web page the way that it should look based on the UIWebView's frame size, it is setting the UIWebView's UIScrollView contentSize to some seemingly arbitrary size (larger than my web view frame size) and loading the responsive web page as it would look for that size frame.

If I try loading the url that I'm using in Safari, it rearranges correctly according to the browser window size.

I have tried setting the scalesPageToFit property to YES, although I don't actually want to scale the page, but have it behave responsively to the web view frame.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: Please show your "responsive" CSS. It sounds like this is implemented incorrectly. This is not about the web view's frame size.

Comment: That may be the case, but the page is responsive in Safari (both on Desktop and in iOS). Why would it not work when loaded into a web view, but work fine when loaded on the iPhone Safari browser? Unfortunately I'm not sure if I can post the css since this is proprietary project for a client.

Comment: "Unfortunately I'm not sure if I can post the css" Well, that's where the action is. You could at least show the _structure_ of the CSS (esp. with regard to media queries, obviously). Also the page's viewport setting might be relevant here.

Comment: Yes, it was the page viewport setting, thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. My UIWebView width on the iPad is smaller than the device width. The web page was using the device width to determine the width of the page (this code was in the <head> element):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I was able to fix the issue using something I found in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113820/472344):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ", (int)webView.frame.size.width]];
}
```

Comment: Should be useful for others. Glad you figured this out!

Comment: Very useful. I tried dozens of similar solutions to this problem found on SO and this is the only one that got it perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, a better place to put the code is inside 'webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:', so that the content is resized  **before** it was shown to the user.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by setting `UIWebView` property `scalesPageToFit` to TRUE.

webView.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;

This help me to use responsive webpage's inside `UIWebView`.

Comment: What a brilliant fix. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use layout constraints in the storyboard. You can simply drag the webview to the parent view and ask for equal width. It is also better to set the constraint from webview to the top layout to 0 to prevent the status bar from overlapping your webview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating an `UIWebView` programmatically and I was adding the `UIWebView` to my `UIView` by using `NSAutoLayoutConstraint`.

```
myWebView = UIWebView()
//Load WebPage
myView.addView(myWebView) // After web page is loaded
//Add constraints
```

I initialized `UIWebView` with a frame and it solved my problem.

```
myWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myView.frame.width, height: myView.frame.height))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For all you Swifters out there, here's a super-clean extension using Darren's answer:

```
extension UIWebView {

    func updateLayoutForContent() {
        let javascript = "document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=\(self.bounds.size.width);', false); "
        self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javascript)
    }

}
```

Handy if you want to call this multiple times (e.g., when the device rotates and the webView changes proportions).