# Setting "device-width" property on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, safari

I'm trying to implement a `UIWebView` that will display `twitter webapp (the iPhone version)`. It's like a little `widget` inside my `iPad app`.

But, I realize the `webapp` uses `"device-width" property` to determine the size of the `webapp`. So, I just can't make `twitter's webapp` fit a 320px width `UIWebView`.

My question: is there someway to "fake" that property and set my own value for it?

BTW: I've already tried this: [displaying Wiki mobile page in UIWebView within UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808579/displaying-wiki-mobile-page-in-uiwebview-within-uipopovercontroller)

It kinda works, it resizes to fit webview's frame. But, for some reason, it makes twitter show the old (very old, and ugly) webapp, instead of the current one.

Here's webview implementation:

```
lateralWeb = [[lateralWebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"lateralWebView" bundle:nil];
lateralWeb.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height);
lateralWeb.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
lateralWeb.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
lateralWeb.webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, self.view.bounds.size.height);

[rootView insertSubview:lateralWeb.view atIndex:0];    

[lateralWeb.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.twitter.com"]]];
```

Here's the code, from lateralWebView.m, that I tried to implement based on the idea from  [displaying Wiki mobile page in UIWebView within UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808579/displaying-wiki-mobile-page-in-uiwebview-within-uipopovercontroller) :

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    if (hasLoaded == NO){
         NSString *webHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:self.webView.request.URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
         NSRange range = [webHTML rangeOfString:@"device-width"];
         if ((range.location!=NSNotFound)&&(range.length != 0)) {   
             webHTML = [webHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"device-width" withString:@"320" options:0 range:range];
             [self.webView loadHTMLString:webHTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.twitter.com"]];
              hasLoaded = YES;
          }
}
}
```

Comment: You could try looking into faking the user agent to make twitter think you're using an iPhone instead of an iPad.

Comment: I've done this already. What It does is simply make webview display the iPhone webapp, instead of the iPad webapp. But, it displays a GIANT iPhone webapp, a 768px wide webapp. Because it gets the "device-width" from iPad.

Comment: Can you post your web view code?