# UIWebView in UIPopover - Report size

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller

I'm displaying a UIWebView in a UIPopoverController in an iOS application.

The iPad is reporting that it's window size is 980x1532. Thus, when I load an external page, it loads and renders 980px wide.

I'm hitting an external website in this webview, so I can't modify any code from the server.

Is there a way to set it so the iPad UIWebView will report the size of the popover (320x480)?

Comment: Why do you need UIWebView to report that size? Are you trying to force the popover to this size?

Comment: Correct. The website has responsive js/css and will be much nicer for my user if it renders in a 320x480 window.

Comment: Then you should just need to set your popover size at creation rather than relying on the web view to do so.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not sure what you mean? I currently set the popover size with `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 480);` in `viewWillAppear`. However, the webview tells the website that it's 980x1532. Is there a better place to set the popover size?

Comment: So the `UIWebView` is resizing the popover itself, after the fact?? I think some code would help me understand.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is probably in the HTML. The page has content="width=device-width" set which sets the uiWebView content size to the size of the device vs the size of the view.

checkout the second answer to this question [displaying Wiki mobile page in UIWebView within UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808579/displaying-wiki-mobile-page-in-uiwebview-within-uipopovercontroller)

it fixed my problem The code is below

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
if(aWebView.frame.size.width < aWebView.window.frame.size.width) {
    // width=device-width results in a wrong viewport dimension for webpages displayed in a popover
    NSString *jsCmd = @"var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');";
    jsCmd = [jsCmd stringByAppendingFormat:@"viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=%i, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1');", (NSUInteger)aWebView.frame.size.width];
    [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCmd];
}
// stop network indicator
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

}

Comment: lots and lots and lots of googling and trying things out :D i wish this answer got accepted :)